# java apache spark mllib

Tags: java, apache, maven

I have started learning mllib apache spark in java. I am following spark 2.1.1 documents from official website. I have spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7 installed in my ubuntu 14.04 lts. I am trying to run this code.

```
public class JavaLogisticRegressionWithElasticNetExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JavaLogisticRegressionWithElasticNetExample") .master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
  // $example on$
    // Load training data
    Dataset<Row> training = spark.read().format("libsvm")
            .load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt");

    LogisticRegression lr = new LogisticRegression()
            .setMaxIter(10)
            .setRegParam(0.3)
            .setElasticNetParam(0.8);

    // Fit the model
    LogisticRegressionModel lrModel = lr.fit(training);

    // Print the coefficients and intercept for logistic regression
    System.out.println("Coefficients: "
            + lrModel.coefficients() + " Intercept: " + lrModel.intercept());

    // We can also use the multinomial family for binary classification
    LogisticRegression mlr = new LogisticRegression()
            .setMaxIter(10)
            .setRegParam(0.3)
            .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
            .setFamily("multinomial");

    // Fit the model
    LogisticRegressionModel mlrModel = mlr.fit(training);

    // Print the coefficients and intercepts for logistic regression with multinomial family
    System.out.println("Multinomial coefficients: " + lrModel.coefficientMatrix()
            + "\nMultinomial intercepts: " + mlrModel.interceptVector());
    // $example off$

    spark.stop();
}
```

}

I have installed spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7 in my system.
I have pom.xml files are

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib-local_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib-local_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but i am getting this exception

> 17/09/08 16:42:19 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.$scope()Lscala/xml/TopScope$;
>   at org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.AllJobsPage.(AllJobsPage.scala:39)
>   at org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.JobsTab.(JobsTab.scala:38)
>   at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.initialize(SparkUI.scala:65)
>   at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.(SparkUI.scala:82)
>   at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:220)
>   at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.createLiveUI(SparkUI.scala:162)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:452)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2320)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
>   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
>   at JavaLogisticRegressionWithElasticNetExample.main(JavaLogisticRegressionWithElasticNetExample.java:12)
>   17/09/08 16:42:19 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
>   17/09/08 16:42:19 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
>   17/09/08 16:42:19 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-8460a189-3039-47ec-8d75-9e0ca8b4ee5d
>   17/09/08 16:42:19 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-8460a189-3039-47ec-8d75-9e0ca8b4ee5d/userFiles-9b6994eb-1376-47a3-929e-e415e1fdb0c0

Comment: so, what's the question/the problem ?

Comment: i am getting exception 17/09/08 16:42:19 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.$scope()Lscala/xml/TopScope$;
 at org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.AllJobsPage.<init>(AllJobsPage.scala:39)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of errors happens when you are using different versions of scala in the same program. And indeed, in your dependencies (in your `pom.xml`), you have some libraries with scala 2.10 and others with scala 2.11.

Use `spark-sql_2.10` instead of `spark-sql_2.11` and you will be fine (or change the mllib versions to 2.11).